# ReactJs - Unable to clear Textarea by resetting value props

Tags: reactjs

My current code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
    };
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.getDetails();
}

//this.getDetails() will load this.state.data, which will have multiple records. Each record has many fields, including "Rationale". 
//Some other functions

render() {

var resolutionList = this.state.data.map((item, index) =>
        <tr key={index} className={(() => { if (item.ScreenChange == "Deleted") return ("danger") })()}>
            <td className="">Some</td>
            <td className="">Other</td>
            <td className="">Table</td>
            <td className="">Data</td>
            <td className="col-sm-3">
                <textarea className="form-control" name={index} id={index} rows="4" cols="50" maxLength="4000" style={{'resize':'none'}}
                    value={item.Rationale}
                    onChange={this.handleRationalChange}
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}
return (
{resolutionList}
)
```

Now I want to force clear the data in the textarea. I created below function to reset the this.state.data. Other fields got updated to blank successfully, except for "Rationale" fields.

Through debugging, I can see this.state.data[i].Rationale is actually null already. However, screen still shows old value. What is missing here?

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={() => this.handleNewForm()}>Clear data</button>

handleNewForm = () => {
    for (i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
        this.state.data[i].some = null;
        this.state.data[i].other = null;
        this.state.data[i].fields = null;
        this.state.data[i].Rationale = null;

    }
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

**EDIT**

I have tried setState, but it either still does not clear data, or gave me syntax error.

This gave me syntax error:

```
this.setState( data[i].Rationale : null);
```

This still does not clear data:

```
this.setState( this.state.data[i].Rationale = null);
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here? I'm having the same issue. I can remove the "value" attribute and it will clear the textbox, but I am using value for some user-validation.

Answer (score 0):

In `handleNewForm` you need to use `setState`, instead of state.

```
handleNewForm = () => {
    for (i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
      this.setState({data[i]: {Rationale: null, other: null}});
    }
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Note that you need to make sure that `data[i]` itself exists and is not null, otherwise you will get an error like `"cannot update value of undefined..."`

Another way that will probably work:

```
dataObj = {...this.state.data[i]};
dataObj.Rationale = null;
dataObj.other = null;                      
this.setState({data[i], dataObj});
```

or

```
dataObj = {...this.state.data[i], Rationale: null, other: null};
this.setState({data[i], dataObj});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm not updating everything in data[i] though. Hence, I still would like to specify what fields I'm updating. Tried this.setState(this.state.data[i].Rationale : null); but it gave me syntax error.

Comment: Updated the reply

Comment: Your updated code threw exactly same syntax error as I got. Basically, after Rationale, it's saying ',' is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setState()` (and your attempt to do so is not valid Javascript). Change your `handleNewForm` function into this:

```
handleNewForm = () => 
  this.setState({
    data: this.state.data.map(dataItem => (
      { 
        ...dataItem, 
        some: null,
        other: null, 
        fields: null, 
        Rationale: null 
      }
    )) 
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael. I copied your code but Rationale value was still there on screen ... :(

Comment: @Henrix React is very picky about what falsy values you use. Try to set it to an empty string (`''`) instead of `null`